# Simple matrix class C++14

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, c++14

I created a simple 4x4 matrix class (column-major). I would like it to be efficient and to use C++14's full capabilities. Can I improve it?

```
#include <array>

class mat4
{
public:
    constexpr mat4() noexcept : matrix() {}

    constexpr mat4(const std::array<float, 16> &m) noexcept : matrix(m) {}
    constexpr mat4(std::array<float, 16> &&m) noexcept : matrix(std::move(m)) {}

    constexpr mat4(const mat4 &other) noexcept : matrix(other.matrix) {}
    constexpr mat4(mat4 &&other) noexcept : matrix(std::move(other.matrix)) {}

    constexpr bool operator==(const mat4 &other) const noexcept
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            if ((*this)[i] != other[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const mat4 &other) const noexcept
    {
        return !(this->operator==(other));
    }

    constexpr mat4& operator+=(const mat4 &other) noexcept
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            (*this)[i] += other[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr mat4& operator*=(float scalar) noexcept 
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            (*this)[i] *= scalar;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    mat4& operator=(mat4 other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(this->matrix, other.matrix);
        return *this;
    }   

    constexpr float& operator[](size_t index) { return const_cast<float&>(static_cast<const std::array<float, 16>&>(matrix)[index]); }
    constexpr float operator[](size_t index) const { return matrix[index]; }

    void print() const noexcept
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("[%.2f][%.2f][%.2f][%.2f]\n", matrix[0], matrix[4], matrix[8], matrix[12]);
        printf("[%.2f][%.2f][%.2f][%.2f]\n", matrix[1], matrix[5], matrix[9], matrix[13]);
        printf("[%.2f][%.2f][%.2f][%.2f]\n", matrix[2], matrix[6], matrix[10], matrix[14]);
        printf("[%.2f][%.2f][%.2f][%.2f]\n", matrix[3], matrix[7], matrix[11], matrix[15]);
    }

private:
    std::array<float, 16> matrix;
};

constexpr const mat4 operator+(mat4 lhs, const mat4 &rhs) noexcept
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

constexpr const mat4 operator*(const mat4 &lhs, const mat4 &rhs) noexcept
{
    mat4 result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
                result[i + 4 * j] += lhs[i + 4 * k] * rhs[k + 4 * j];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

constexpr const mat4 operator*(mat4 lhs, float scalar) noexcept 
{
    lhs *= scalar;
    return lhs;
}
```

You can test it in this [live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf2cc80d38c413cd).

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek It compiles under g++ (although I haven't called the functions).  I 'm assuming it's differentiating by one function being `const` and the other not.

Comment: @forsvarir, thanks. Missed the const, which is part of the function signature.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how I feel about you hardcoding that this should be a 4x4 matrix of floats, and that it should be column major. It seems straightforward enough to make a templated class like so

```
template <typename T, size_t numRows, size_t numCols>
class Matrix {
...
};

using mat4 = Matrix<float, 4, 4>;
```

It might also be worthwhile to have a boolean template parameter for whether or not it should be row or column major; in my experience many applications assume something is row major, and interfacing with your application might yield some unexpected issues.

If you do so, then I think adding a constructor to switch row/column major would be worthwhile as well.

I personally like using `operator()` instead of `operator[]` for getting a value at a given row and column; I feel like in general it shouldn't be up to the user to manually calculate the 1d index.  Something along the lines of this:

```
constexpr const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const noexcept 
{
    return matrix[col * numCols + row];
}

constexpr T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) noexcept
{
    return matrix[col * numCols + row];
}
```

I also generally assume that `at()` (or similar) will be provided if indexing (or `operator()`-like access) is provided.

Don't use a member function like `print()`; instead implement `operator<<` so people can use it with their own streams as desired.  I see you're using `printf` - why? I've definitely used it before in my programs, but I usually think of it as a code-smell. If you want to add `printf` support that's fine, but I would argue that streams should be prioritized.

Your `operator==` is unnecessarily complicated - [`std::array` implements it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp).

I don't like using `this->` to refer to member functions; just use them.  Then your `operator!=` becomes `return !operator==(other)`.

`operator+=` and `operator*=` can be done using [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/).

You should implement iterators for your matrix as well. Whether you make them row-major or column-major shouldn't matter, but be consistent (assuming you make it possible to switch between orientations). No matter the orientation, the iteration order should be the same.

You should add some improved matrix multiplication algorithms (or, ideally, use a library that does it for you). With some SFINAE wizardry you can probably make a vectorized version, a tiled version, etc.  Probably only necessary if you actually make it possible to use larger matrices, although vectorization will probably still be a bit faster even for a small one.

Comment: Great answer! The reason why I only considered designing a 4d column-major square matrix class is because I'm only using matrices in OpenGL but I'll definitely switch to a template as I'm going to need 3d matrices too. As for `operator==` of `std::array` and `std::transform`, I've already thought on using them but they are not `constexpr` functions and you cannot call them within another `constexpr` function. I also gave up on the idea of using them because they do not seem to be really faster than a basic for loops  (for `std::transform` at least when I looked up its implementation).

Comment: @Corvinus They won't necessarily be faster, but they're easier to read imo.  If they're not constexpr that's a dealbreaker though, unless you think you could implement your own version that is.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to answer my own question. I would be grateful if anyone could comment on it weither they agree/do not agree with parts of my solution.

---

- #### The first argument of type `mat4` should be passed by reference rather than by value in `operator+`, `operator*` (scalar version) and `operator=` signatures.

With the help of this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) let's carry out an analysis of the function `operator+` (like it is done in this [article](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/want-speed-dont-always-pass-by-value/)) to understand why (analysis for `operator*` and `operator=` is similar).

Fist, we can assume **two things** on the code above :

1. When the conditions for **copy elision** are met, the compiler will omit copy or move constructors of `mat4`. I have tested this under **GCC 6.1** and **Clang 3.8** and it is indeed the case in all the situations I've tested when using the operators of this class.
2. For this class `mat4`, that **default constructor** **>=** **copy constructor** **=** **move constructor** (the greater the faster in terms of execution speed). Because `std::array` is an **aggregate**, moving a `float` is not any faster than copying it. **Copy/move constructor** probably use something like `memcpy` internally and the **default constructor** `memset` (because of the call `matrix()` in `mat4`'s constructor) to set all elements to 0 (which I doubt would be slower than `memcpy` and may be even faster).

There are two cases to consider when calling `operator+` :

1. The first argument of type `mat4` passed to the function is a **lvalue**.
2. It is a **rvalue**.

If the first argument is an **lvalue**, the pass-by-value (current) version of `operator+` will call the **copy constructor** of `mat4` to copy that object into `lhs`. Then when the function returns, it will call the **move constructor** of `mat4` to move `lhs` into the object returned by `operator+`. The reason why it is the move and not the copy constructor that is called is explained in the reference given above. Here is the interesting extract :

> **(since C++11)** In a return statement or a throw-expression, if the compiler cannot perform copy elision but the conditions for copy elision are met or would be met, except that the source is a function parameter, the compiler will attempt to use the move constructor even if the object is designated by an lvalue; see return statement for details.

However, if the argument passed to `operator+` is an **rvalue**, copy of that value into **lhs** will be elided. In this case only the **move constructor** is called.

Now let's do the exact same analysis for the pass-by-reference version of `operator+` which I propose the implementation to be the following :

```
constexpr const mat4 operator+(const mat4 &lhs, const mat4 &rhs) noexcept
{
    mat4 result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

In both cases, i.e. when the first argument to the function is either an **lvalue** or an **rvalue**, calling the function will only result in a **single** call of the **default constructor** (`mat4 result;`). Note that the temporary object `result` will not be moved nor copied into the function's returned value because the conditions for **copy elision** are met.

**Conclusion** : **this last solution is undeniably faster**. Be careful, it is not everytime the case and only true here because of how `operator+` can be implemented and because of the two assumptions, especially the second one, i.e. **default constructor** **>=** **copy constructor** **=** **move constructor** (note that this conclusion would also be true if **default constructor** **=** **copy constructor** **=** **move constructor**).

---

- #### In operator=, it is unnecessary to use std::swap because you do unnecessary copies.

  Just use `this->matrix = other.matrix;`. `std::swap` would only be interesting to use if the class implemented a **resource** (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)).

---

- #### Until complete `constexpr` support for `std::array` (C++17), you could create your own array wrapper and so you wouldn't have to write that ugly cast in `operator[]`

Here is a wrapper inspired from `std::array` that could work :

```
template<class _Ty, size_t _Size>
struct arr
{
    constexpr _Ty& operator[](size_t index) noexcept
    {
        return _arr[index];
    }
    constexpr const _Ty& operator[](size_t index) const noexcept
    {
        return _arr[index];
    }

    constexpr _Ty *data() noexcept
    {
        return _arr;
    }

    constexpr const _Ty *data() const noexcept
    {   
        return _arr;
    }

    float _arr[_Size];
};
```